# Which Numbers Replace the Question Marks?

Tags: mathematics, sequence

Can you find out what the numbers below have in common? Can you figure out what comes next?

```
I = 9,9,9,8,8,8,2,7,?

II = 6,6,7,5,7,5,1,3,?

III = 4,8,4,8,4,8,5,3,?

IV = 5,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,?

V = 2,8,1,4,7,2,8,6,?

VI = 9,8,7,5,4,3,3,5,?

VII = 2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,?

VIII = 3,6,1,2,2,4,0,1,?
```

Comment: Are the 8 sequences related? Or are they separate?

Comment: They are separate. :)

Comment: Mmm. That makes this extremely difficult. You might find it gets closed as too broad. It becomes a "guess what's in my head" if there's no connecting theme.

Comment: I believe the OP means that the eight sequences follow the same algorithm, but in different cases

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder what the 7th one is? I know! 5! (just joking)

Answer (score 1):

I. 9,9,9,8,8,8,2,7,12

II. 6,6,7,5,7,5,1,3,11

III. 4,8,4,8,4,8,5,3,16

IV. 5,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7

V. 2,8,1,4,7,2,8,6,1

VI. 9,8,7,5,4,3,3,5,-8

VII. 2,0,2,0,2,0,0

VIII. 3,6,1,2,2,4,0,1,5

I. (9+9+9)-(8+8+8)=3 (8+8+8)-(2+7+12)=3

II. (6+6+7)-(5+7+5)=2 (5+7+5)-(1+3+11)=2

III. (4+8+4)-(8+4+8)=-4 (8+4+8)-(5+3+16)=-4

IV. (5+5+5)-(6+6+6)=-3 (6+6+6)-(6+8+7)=-3

V. (2+8+1)-(4+7+2)=-2 (4+7+2)-(8+6+1)=-2

VI. (9+8+7)-(5+4+3)=12 (5+4+3)-(3+5-8)=12

VII. (2+0+2)-(0+2+0)=2 (0+2+0)-(0)=2

VIII. (3+6+1)-(2+2+4)=2 (2+2+4)-(0+1+5)=2

Answer (score 0):

I guess the 1. solution is...

> $8 * 3 = 24$, because there are three times a 9 and $9 * 3 = 27$

The 4. answer could be...

> $68 + 20 = 88$, because if you erase the commas, you get $55 + 1 = 56, 56 + 10 = 66, 66 + 2 = 68$

The 5. answer could be...

> $3$, because if you erase the commas, all numbers are multiples of $7$, the only 2 digit number starting with $6$ and being a multiple of $7$ is $63$

The 6. answer could be...

> $98 - 75 = 23$, $75 - 43 = 32$, $43 - 35 = 8$, you can see, that the difference of the first pairs is mirrored, so maybe the next number is $35 - 8 = 27$

The 7. answer could be...

> $3$, because there are $2^2 = 4$ times the number 2, separated of $0$. So my idea is, that the sequence continues with $3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,4,0,...$

The 8. sequence could work...

> like the 5. If all numbers are multiples of $3$, the last number could be $5$ or $8$, if all numbers are multiples of $6$, the last number could be $8$